# Parsing array into a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code to return some api information:

```
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonfile);
print_r($jsondata->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance);
```

This displays the following data on the webpage:

```
stdClass Object ([text] => 91.4 mi[value] => 147088 )
```

What I need to know, is how to convert the value field (e.g. `[value]=147088`) to a variable that I can save within my database, e.g. how do I get

```
$value = xxxxx
```

Comment: Just keep it going: `$value = $jsondata->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->value;`

Comment: Also not that these are _not_ arrays, but _objects_ .

Comment: @arkascha, well `routes` and `legs` are arrays ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sure, I was referring to the distances when writing "these"...

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the community.

Use the code below:

```php
<?php
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonfile, true);
extract($jsondata);
```

How this code works:

1- I added a second parameter to the `json_decode()` function which is a Boolean and if it is true it will return an array instead of an object.

2- `extract()` function will assign a array value to its key as a variable. Like:

```php
<?php
$my_array = ["firstname" => "Adnan", "lastname" => "Babakan"];
extract($my_array);
// $firstname = "Adnan";
// $lastname = "Babakan";
```

I hope this was your answer.